# angularjs multiple select not working with array of mongodb objectids

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I must be doing something wrong. My select box is not selecting any options. Am I missing something, or do I need to change the data in some way?

HTML:

```
<select ng-options="item._id as item.title for item in articles" ng-model="article.related" multiple></select>
```

articles looks like:

```
[
  {
    _id: 328749832743aeeaa28434a87,
    title: 'Some title'
  },
  ...
]
```

article.related looks like:

```
[
  28749832743aeeaa28434a87,
  328749832743aeeaa28434a88,
  ...
]
```

Comment: if you display the content of your articles variable with the {{articles}} expression just below your select, can you see them?
Your code seem to be correct.

Comment: Oh man, I was populating article.related for some reason. Removed that and it is working now. I guess put that as the answer, and I'll mark it.